# Value switcher for groups in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
groups = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']
```

I need to map each value to have an output like this, independently from the numbers of groups and elements inside:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
```

The values in output should switch every time when the group is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [python](/questions/tagged/python)

With a list comprehension and the walrus operator of python 3.8+:

```
groups = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']

flag = 0

out = [flag if a==b else (flag:=1-flag) for a, b in zip(groups, groups[:1]+groups)]
```

Or `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable([i%2]*len(list(g))
           for i, (_, g) in enumerate(groupby(groups))))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

### Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

out = pd.factorize(groups)[0]%2
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(groups)
out = (s.ne(s.shift(fill_value=s[0]))
       .cumsum().mod(2).tolist()
       )
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

### Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

out = np.cumsum(groups != np.r_[groups[:1], groups[:-1]])%2
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another O(n) solution:

```py
def value_switcher(groups):
    if not groups:
        return groups
    new_groups = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(groups)):
        if groups[i-1] != groups[i]:
            if new_groups[i-1] == 0:
                new_groups.append(1)
            else:
                new_groups.append(0)
        else:
            new_groups.append(new_groups[i-1])
    return new_groups
```

I tested it as follows:

```py
groups = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']
assert value_switcher(groups) == [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
groups = ['A']
assert value_switcher(groups) == [0]
groups = ['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
assert value_switcher(groups) == [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
groups = []
assert value_switcher(groups) == []
groups = None
assert value_switcher(groups) is None
```